# Where to properly place script so it will execute?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, document-ready

I'm having a problem, I never had before with Bootstrap 3 modal window. I scroll down to close the bootstrap modal window and reopen it to find out it saves the position I last closed it at. Normally, it would reset the scroll every time I reopen it, but this time it doesn't.

```
        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></a>
                <img src="images/sunset1.jpg" alt="me"/>
                <h2>Content test</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

So I found this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e){
        $('.modal-content').scrollTop(0);
    });  
});
```

to be the solution to my answer, but then again it won't run it. I debugged it and analyzed that when I put this in an external js file (custom.js), as the page is loading, it will recognize the `$(document).ready` function, but never enter it. I also tried putting it at the bottom of the html page where the same result happens and lastly I also tried creating a new script under the modal to run, but it will give me a `Reference error: $ not defined` message and I know it has to be put after jQuery plugin is called.. at the bottom. If I eliminate the `$(document).ready` function, it will still recognize the modal function in all cases, but still never execute. I'm pretty much lost as to how to get this function working?

---

**EDIT:**

```
<head>
<!-- Included script in head to run and fix bootstrap modal scroll 'save' position -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e){
        $('.modal-content').scrollTop(0);
    });  
});
</script>
</head>




     <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></a>
                    <img src="images/sunset1.jpg" alt="me"/>
                    <h2>Content test</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

**Solution by DelightedD0D:**

Modified script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e){
        $('#myModal').scrollTop(0); // change from .model-content to #myModal
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I already tried putting a script tag under the modal. Do you suggest, I put the jQuery library in the head section or?

Comment: are you really missing the `<body>` tags in your code, or is that a typo here?

Comment: No, just a typo here, I have the body tags in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you sorted on the placement of the code. Dont forget to give your modal div the id `myModal`, your current HTML doesn't have it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
        alert('Modal was shown!');
        // $('#myModal').scrollTop(0);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>


<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="bg">Click to open modal</a> 


<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></a>
                <img src="images/sunset1.jpg" alt="me"/>
                <h2>Content test</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum erat et neque tincidunt volutpat. Cras eget augue id dui varius pretium. Cras posuere dolor risus. Pellentesque elementum ultricies quam, sit amet rhoncus nisl viverra in. Cras imperdiet nisi a euismod molestie. Ut a metus arcu. Pellentesque feugiat dictum erat.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made an edit to the post above with your suggested changes, but it still doesn't work. When the page loads, it seems the script reached the end of the `$(document).ready` function here `});` and that was only time it ran, nothing else. I'm not sure it has anything to do with it, but the Global scope returned `undefined`.

Comment: Same exact problem, I think it may be a glitch or a conflict with other libraries. I know there is a solution to every problem, but this one is the longest and still no solution. I still don't understand why it won't go through when it should. :(

Comment: is your page online somewhere viewable?

Comment: sure, maybe we can help If we can see it not working

Comment: I put it up live but the university servers are not going through. Is it possible for me to send it to you locally to view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68936/discussion-between-delightedd0d-and-theamazingknight).